# ReflectiveInjector vs Injector when creating a dynamic components in Angular 5+

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular2-components

After migrating to Angular v.5.2.9 noticed a deprecation message:

> ReflectiveInjector is deprecated: from v5 - slow and brings in a lot of code, Use `Injector.create` instead.

Before Angular v5 I have created dynamic components like this:

#### ReflectiveInjector

```
// Old API with ReflectiveInjector
createWithReflectiveInjector() {
  // Inputs need to be in the following format to be resolved properly
  const resolvedInputs = ReflectiveInjector.resolve([
  { provide: "options", useValue: this.data }
  ]);

  // Clear the template before inserting new one
  this.dynamicComponentContainer.clear();

  // We create an injector out of the data we want to pass down and this components injector
  const injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders(
    resolvedInputs,
    this.dynamicComponentContainer.parentInjector
  );

  // We create a factory out of the component we want to create
  const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(CounterWithInject);

  // We create the component using the factory and the injector
  const component = factory.create(injector);

  // Subscribe to Output events:
  component.instance.resetCounter.subscribe(() => {
    this.data.count = 0;
  });

  // We insert the component into the dom container
  this.dynamicComponentContainer.insert(component.hostView);
}
```

I have refactored to updated API with **Injector.create()**:

#### Injector

```
createWithInjector() {
  const inputs = [{ provide: "options", useValue: this.data }];

  // Clear the template before inserting new one
  this.dynamicComponentContainer2.clear();

  const injector = Injector.create({
    providers: inputs,
    parent: this.dynamicComponentContainer2.parentInjector
  });

  // We create a factory out of the component we want to create
  const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(CounterWithInput);

  // Destroy the previously created component
  if (this.componentRef) {
    this.componentRef.destroy();
  }

  this.componentRef = this.dynamicComponentContainer2.createComponent(
  factory, 0, injector);

  // We insert the component into the dom container
  this.dynamicComponentContainer2.insert(this.componentRef.hostView);

  this.componentRef.instance.resetCounter.subscribe(() => {
    this.data.count = 0;
  });
}
```

And it's actually pretty the same piece of code even after switching to new Injector API.

My questions are:
1)Maybe I'm missing something in docs and creating dynamic components could be much simplified in Angular v5+?
2)Noticed that in [official doc](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#resolving-components) input data providing with extending instance of a component, like this:

```
let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
(<AdComponent>componentRef.instance).data = adItem.data;
```

And what the preferred way to provide props to dynamic components:
**with the providers**:

```
const inputs = [{ provide: "options", useValue: { count: 0} }];
const injector = Injector.create({
  providers: inputs,
  parent: this.dynamicComponentContainer2.parentInjector
});
```

and read the injected props in component:

```
...
ngOnInit() {
  this.options = this.injector.get("options") || {};
}
```

**with the instance extend**:

```
// Define input data
this.componentRef.instance.data = { count: 0 };
```

and get the *@Input()* in the component:

```
export class CounterWithInput implements OnInit {
  @Input() data: any;
}
```

Live demo with approaches: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/7j693j6zqq)